# Explanation of bitwise operation

Tags: java, android, colors

I have a very simple question: I want to know what is the meaning of this java operation. I'm a beginner in java and can't understand what it does. I know that it is a packed int storing a color

```
(alpha << 24) | (red << 16) | (green << 8) | blue
```

Another question: I want to go from a 0xFFFFFFFF value to a RGB type color, how can I separate this packed int into RGB channels?

Comment: Visit this page for description: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Regarding the first question:**

The expressison is loading four 8-bit quantities into a 32-bit int. Although generally this kind of boolean manipulation is done with unsigned ints to avoid complications I won't go into here.

The line you're showing is shifting the alpha component's value (e.g. its 8-bits) 24 bits to the left, to create a result which has alpha  occupying the high-order byte of a 4-byte (32-bit) integer.

Then it shifting the red component 16 bits to the left (increasing its numeric value binary orders of magnitude), and logically ORing the result of that shift operation into the 32-bit integer that alpha was stored in, merging in the value, to occupy the 3rd byte. The result at that point will be that the top two bytes will have the alpha and red values, and so on.

**Regarding the second question:**

You can invert the procedure and use boolean operators:

```
unsigned int v = 0xff557788;
int blue = v & 0xff;
int green = v >> 8 & 0xff;
int red = v >> 16 & 0xff;
int alpha = v >> 24 & 0xff;
```

In this example we're shifting the field right in multiples of 8 to get the different bytes into the lowest byte, and then masking (e.g. logically ANDing with) 0xff to get a value that excludes the high order 3 bytes.